# Date difference between consecutive rows for each group in pyspark df

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, window, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark df sorted on basis of date for each group like below -

[image]

Now in this dataframe, I want to create a new date-difference column which will give the date differences between two consecutive dates for each group like below -

[image]

I have tried this -

[image]

Also I have tried this -

[image]

Both of them throwing the same error as follows -

[image]

Comment: Do not add your code blocks as image.

Comment: I think you somewhere  copy pasted the code, that's why you are getting this error. try typing the second variant of your code and run.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work as expected if you change the date format to `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Check below code

```
WITH source AS (
  SELECT 
    a, 
    b,
    group_name,
    to_date(date,'MM/dd/yyyy') as date,
    order
  FROM VALUES 
  (1, 4, 'GFG1', '08/01/2000', 1),
  (1, 4, 'GFG1', '10/01/2000', 2),
  (1, 4, 'GFG1', '12/01/2000', 3),
  (2, 8, 'GFG2', '06/02/2000', 1),
  (4, 5, 'GFG3', '05/03/2000', 1),
  (4, 5, 'GFG3', '12/03/2000', 2)
  AS (a, b, group_name, date, order)
)
SELECT 
  a, 
  b, 
  group_name, 
  date, 
  order, 
  (DATE_DIFF(date, LAG(date, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY date))) AS date_difference
FROM source
```